# Asymptotic rate of convergence versus the "asymptotics" of any series expansion

Tags: statistics, reference-request, asymptotics

On page 68 of Christopher Small's Expansions and Asymptotics for Statistics, we look at:
$$
E(T_n)=\sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi n}}e^{-n/8}\Big(1-\frac{8}{n}+\frac{96}{n^2}-\cdots\Big).
$$
(Here, $n$ is the sample size and $T_n$ is a function of the observed data.)

The authors then write:

> In this example, the **asymptotic rate of convergence** of $T_n$ to zero
>   is **superexponential**. However, the expansion is "**$n$-asymptotic**" in
>   nature.

(The boldfacing is mine.)

Up to the page cited above, the boldfaced terms above are not defined rigorously. What do they refer to and could you please recommend a more elementary text that deal with (topics that eventually lead to) those terms?

Comment: Have you researched the literature to find the definitions of the terms of interest?

Comment: @MarkViola I googled but didn't see anything up to my liking and that was why I posted here, hoping to find them in one accessible source.

Comment: @MarkViola I also looked at the references cited at the end of the book chapter containing the quote above. They are: Spivak's Calculus, Witttake and Watson's A Course of Modern Analysis, and Wong's Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals.